# How to display an image in a new window

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview

I have a follow-on question to [How to display an image based on SelectedValue in a GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097438/how-to-display-an-image-based-on-selectedvalue-in-a-gridview)

What I would really like to do is have a ViewImage button on my GridView control so that when that is clicked, the image is displayed on a new page in a new browser window. How would I do that? I'm thinking perhaps do I need to create a

```
<asp:ButtonField>
```

How do I handle the click and how do I get the image to diplay on a new form in a new web browser window?

Thanks very much for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TemplateColumn, in that TemplateColumn you can define a button where you put javascript function to open new window.

Example:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:ShowImageInNewPage('PageToShowImage.aspx?tradeId=<%# Eval("TradeId") %>');" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The "ShowImageInNewPage" function is a custom function you declare to popup/open new window with the selected image url.

In PageToShowImage.aspx, declare an img tag:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgBlah" runat="server" />
```

In code behind of PageToShowImage.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is querystring from GridView page
    if(Request.QueryString["tradeId"] != null)
    {
        imgBlah.Src = "GetImage.aspx?entityId=" + tradeId + "&entityType=T";
    }
    else
    {
        imgBlah.Src = "~/images/no-image.jpg"; // set no image
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks I've created a javascript function to open a new window. However the image is being retrieved from a database and is handled by a page called GetImage.aspx which takes a querystring as shown in the link in my question. I feel like I'm getting tangled up in code here and I'm not sure how to populate the URL with my parameters. How can I add the current row's tradeId (the primary key) to the ImageURL?

Comment: One more thing, do you know of a way to get the new opened window to resize itself to the size of the image?

Comment: It would be easy if the image has a fixed size, just use parameters for window.open javascript function on your page with the GridView. If not then you will have to get the size information on the GridView page and pass it as parameters for window.open function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping that you're dealing with browser supported image formats.  Assuming you are, you don't need a `ButtonField`.  One approach would be to use an `<asp:HyperLink>` in a `TemplateColumn`, as Arief suggested.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperLink1" runat="server" NavigatUrl="UrlToYourViewImagePage" Text="View Image" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you want the image to open in a new window, build a [window.open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx) call for each HyperLink's NavigateUrl.

Comment: Yes I am using .gif images stored in SQL Server. I'm not really sure what I should put in the NavigateURL because as mentioned in my comment to Arief I have another page called GetImage.aspx handle the image request from the database. Could you help with that? I'm also unsure how I would format it so that it would call the javascript function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I decided to use Arief's solution.